# SailsJS - Dynamically loading config without a restart

Tags: javascript, express, sails.js

Is it possible to dynamically update a `sails.config` object without having to relift sails to apply those changes?

I'm looking to dynamically update the `sails.config.policies`

In my `bootstrap.js` I have set

```
sails.config.policies = JSON.parse(myJSONString);
```

Which sets the values fine, but they never get applied.

Alternatively, is there any way of moving the `sails.config files` into a db and have them load from there on lift?

**UPDATE**

After following Andrea Rega suggestion, I moved my logic out and created a separate "allowedaccess" policy. I then added a new Model which maps out a users role to a route and pull that in within the policy. The user's role is then checked with the role->permission list in the database.

Comment: do you mean during the development workflow or into production?

Comment: Whilst the app is running in production.

Comment: so what is the purpose? Are you trying to add a custom Authorization and User Rights Management layer?

Comment: Yes, to allow a user to update user policies on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in my opinion a better approach could be putting the **Policy layer** as an **infrastructural layer** and the **Authorization management layer** as an **application layer**.

This is because you have to be able to change or configure your authorization at runtime, as a part of your applcation features, instead the sails policies are somethig **static**.

An example can be a policy `isFeature1UserEnabled` where an `AuthorizationController` is used in order to fetch the specific authorization for the "feature1" for the given user

Then in your `sails.config.policies` you will specify that for the method `method1` a series of policies must be satisfied.

With this approach you are able to manage all your user right dinamically and then delegate to the sails policies to verify them and check all the related authorization contraints.

I hope this could help you

Comment: Thanks. This is a far more sane way of solving it than my initial idea.